# Apache Camel - Spring Web App - Camel Context not started on @PostConstruct

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-camel

I have an Apache-Camel Web Application that is using Spring. I have certain routes with the property
`autoStartup=false` so I can conditionally start them based on some checks I do when the application starts. In order to do that I have the logic in a `@PostConstruct` init method.
However once the @PostConstruct method has been loaded the CamelContext has been **constructed** but not **started**. Therefore the routeDefinitions have not yet being loaded. So if I do `camelContext.startRoute("myRoute")`. Nothing happens. On the other hand if I expose this method as a web-service the route starts normally as expected. This is my controller below:

```
@Controller
public class EntryBean implements CamelContextAware {

    private CamelContext camelContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //at this point the started property is still false
        //and the camelContext does have any routeDefinitions
        camelContext.startRoute("myRoute");
    }

    @RequestMapping("startRoutes")
    @ResponseBody
    public String startCamelRoutes() {
        //this runs normally when called from the GET request
        camelContext.startRoute("myRoute");
        return "Routes Started Succesfully";
    }

    @Override
    public void setCamelContext(CamelContext camelContext) {
        this.camelContext = camelContext;
    }

    @Override
    public CamelContext getCamelContext() {
        return camelContext;
    }
}
```

I have even used `<bean class="org.example.EntryBean" depends-on="camelContext"/>` but still nothing.

Comment: Why do you need to start the route in the post construction method? BTW, camel context just add the route when it is started.

Comment: I need to start the routes manually (based on conditions which I dont have in the example, as soon as the .war is deployed. So I thought the @PostConstruct method would be the most appropriate.